# iPhone And iPad versions under the same App ID

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

i already have an iPhone app on the App Store, and recently finished the iPad version of the same App.

I cant seem to find a way to upload the iPad version under the same App name (app id) on iTunes connect.

Uploading different app packages for different devices is possible on the Google Play Store.

So, is it possible to do this on the App Store? is so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a single universal app under the original app id, not two separate apps. Basically, update the existing iPhone app to be universal and include the iPad parts. Then submit the newly universal version of the app as an update to the existing iPhone app.

If you really want two separate apps (there's no good reason for this) then the iPad app must have a different app id and a different name.