# Can we submit the iPhone and iPad version of an app on iTunes store?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have an iPad app it is already on app store, and converted my iPad app into an iPhone app. Now I want to submit my app for both iPhone and iPad version using same bundle id.

Comment: Are you using two separate projects for iPad and iPhone???

Comment: not possible to have 2 apps with the same bundle id as far as i know... you should have made the one app handle both ipad and iphone

Comment: If is it is a single project you can submit to appstore.

Comment: @Madhu it means i have same project which I create iphone and ipad

Comment: you can't use same bundle identifier for two different apps. you can make your app compatible for iPhone and iPad and submit again.

Comment: yes, you need to have single project where you are optimizing the app for iphone and ipad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone And iPad versions under the same App ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640338/iphone-and-ipad-versions-under-the-same-app-id)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have made the one app handle both iPad and iPhone.
In single Project while building you set the Deployment device as Universal on project target.
And submit this build to AppStore,
AppStore Allow only **Single build for iPad & iPhone**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two separate projects then its not possible to use single bundle identifier. if you want to use single bundle identifier , you can create a single **universal app** so that you can use same identifier for both iPad and iPhone.